# Serving JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, firewall, jsapi

I am using some of the services from Google via JSAPI (Charting and some others).

One of my clients is big university/campus (which is behind strict firewall), and they are not allowing third party gzip files to be downloaded. I had some other vendors that I used, and they were also serving their files in gzip coming from their CDN.

I was able to simply donwload their JS files and serve them myself. Client has no problem with that as long as the gzip is coming from me.

I was looking for solution to serve files from Google myself, but was unable to find a solution. Has anyone done this before? Is there a trick solution, as I would really like to continue using Google libs.

Comment: Use a PHP proxy server.

Comment: Could you please provide more information regarding proxy solution?

Comment: http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/

Comment: SO in essence, I have backbone running in express and that talks to Sails.js server... it means that I need to setup somewhere (within the domain) PHP running that will call JSAPI files on demand. I will take a look at this script